# Eclipse Hawkbit - Actions History API

Tags: eclipse-hawkbit, hawkbit

I am trying to get some information about the action history of a target but I can't find anything helpful in the API docs, regarding actions states and messages. Am I missing something?

Here is what I want to obtain from the APIs:

[image: hawkbit actions view]

This data is available in their interface, but i could not find an endpoint to provide it in the API's docs.

UPDATE:
I found what I was looking for.
Calling /rest/v1/targets/{controller-id}/actions/{action-id} will provide a URL to action status which will return the data displayed in the picture above.

Answer (score 1):

Management APIs and DDI APIs are documented on [Actions](https://eclipse.dev/hawkbit/rest-api/mgmt.html#tag/Actions) and [DDI API](https://eclipse.dev/hawkbit/apis/ddi_api/)

Based on the screenshot you want to look at [Actions](https://eclipse.dev/hawkbit/rest-api/mgmt.html#tag/Actions)